# php function with 2 arguments

Tags: php, function

I have a function with 2 arguments. Here it is

```
function listBoats($con,$table){
    //get record set for all boats sort them by their "sort" number
    $queryBoat = "SELECT * FROM " .$table. " WHERE `id` <> 'mainPage' ORDER BY `sort` LIMIT 0, 1000";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$queryBoat);
    return $result;
}
```

here is how I'm calling it

```
$result = listBoats($con,"CSINSTOCK"); //run query to list all the boats in the CSINSTOCK table
```

I can't get it to work. But If I add the variable `$table = "CSINSTOCK"` inside the function it does work. Why wont the function pass the `"CSINSTOCK"` variable through?

Comment: For best results, don't assume that `mysqli_query()` is successful. You should check the result and use `mysqli_error()` to return any errors.

Comment: For starters I would var_dump($con) and var_dump($table) inside the function to make sure what you're intending to pass is arriving.  I would guess that theres probably an error being suppressed but its hard to guess without a better description than "doesn't work"

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: It should be noted that case-sensitivity may be an issue (this depends on whether the underlying OS is case-sensitive). Also, I don't think 'CSINSTOCK' is a MySQL reserved word, but encapsulating the table name in backticks couldn't hurt.

Comment: When I say doesn't work I mean the function simply doesn't run.

Comment: can you try `echo`ing the query?

Comment: @DougSteinberg - In PHP, if you invoke a function it runs (unless PHP crashes in the meantime). Do you get a crash?

Comment: you can TRIVIALLY confirm the function is being invoked with a `var_dump($table)` inside the function. NEVER assume a query has been successful. always check for failure.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use PDO. Here is an example

**EXAMPLE.**
This is your dbc class (dbc.php)

```
<?php

class dbc {

    public $dbserver = 'server';
    public $dbusername = 'user';
    public $dbpassword = 'pass';
    public $dbname = 'db';

    function openDb() {    
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("error, please try again");
        }        
        return $db;
    }

    function getAllData($qty) {
        //prepared query to prevent SQL injections
        $query = "select * from TABLE where qty = ?";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $qty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
    }    
?>
```

your PHP page:

```
<?php 
require "dbc.php";

$getList = $db->getAllData(25);

foreach ($getList as $key=> $row) {
         echo $row['columnName'] .' key: '. $key;
    }
```

If you have the access to your database you should be able to perform your required operations.

Comment: it doesn't answer the actual question, it could be a comment